# Xamarin Error: Can not find the object referenced by

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a bit of a problem with Xamarin Data Binding. When binding to an item in a C# class, I get the error seen in the title. I've been trying to bind an element from the table example found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/tableview#custom-cells). I tried adding `BindingContext = this;` to the constructor and to change the line above the class declaration to `[DesignTimeVisible(false)]` the way it is in the `NewItemPage` from the Master-Detail template found during the creation of the project, however, it did not help.

Here is the code:

XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="NetworkScanner.Views.TestPage">
    <TableView>
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Getting Started" BindingContext="{x:Reference Table}">
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="bulb.png" />
                        <Label Text="left"
                                 TextColor="#f35e20" />
                        <Label Text="right"
                                 HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                 TextColor="#503026" />
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </TableSection>
        </TableRoot>
    </TableView>
</ContentPage>
```

C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace NetworkScanner.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    // [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class TestPage : ContentPage
    {
        public TableSection Table { get; set; }
        public TestPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // BindingContext = this;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?  You are setting the BindingContext, but do not have any binding expressions, and you never initialize your `Table` property.  Generally if you want a table that is data driven you would use a ListView or CollectionVIew, not a TableView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the keyword Binding instead of x:Reference.

```
<TableSection Title="Getting Started" BindingContext="{Binding Table}">
```

Comment: It doesn't result in a build error any more, but the value of Table is still null.

Comment: Its null because you have to Create instance of TableSection.

Comment: In constructor create instance like "Table = new TableSection();" or if you don't want to create it give x:Name property to TableSection in your XAML or in your cs file give this name to Table property. 
<TableSection x:Name="section"> in XAML
Table = section;     in backend.